# What's for com.example.asd.fileprovider in manifest

Tags: android, android-studio

In the app manifest file I have an 'application' tag with android authorities value 'com.example.asd.fileprovider'. It looks like it should be in provider tag but instead is in application tag. Is it required ? What's for ? Should i remove it from the application tag and create additional 'provider' tag ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    package="com.aaa.bbb.ccc"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name="com.aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:authorities="com.example.asd.fileprovider"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/xxxTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="com.aaa.bbb.ccc.activity.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.aaa.bbb.ccc.activity.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.aaa.bbb.ccc.activity.RegisterActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.aaa.bbb.ccc.activity.ObjectActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>


        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="zedzedzedzejdnzededdzedzedezdez" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It's a [provider element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html). Not quite sure what you are asking...

Comment: Read the question one more time. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's for ?

There is no use for that attribute. [The `<application>` element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) does not have an `authorities` attribute.

> Should i remove it from the application tag

Yes.

> and create additional 'provider' tag ?

Only if you have a `ContentProvider`, for which you wish to use that authority name.